# python 3.0 tkinter, how to repeat a function that gets a returned value each button press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, widget

As you will see with the following code, I am a professional coder, but I am stuck on this very simple task.

The purpose of the code is to randomly generate a string, match that string to a string in a list, and then return the string + the attribute so then when its pulled by the button widget, it presents the card in its whole. (the name and then the story.) However, it only generates the same card. I want it to generate a new card on each button press. Yes, I am aware that the `<Return>` refers to the enter key, thats just an easier way to for me to confirm its not working.

```
import _thread
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import random
import re
import time
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

top = tkinter.Tk()

def presentcard():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("this is your card", what)    

thebutton = tkinter.Button(top, text = "Pull a card out.", command = presentcard)

class Allthecards:
    def __init__(self,name,story):
        self.name = name
        self.story = story

card1 = Allthecards("The Beast", "It eats things")
card2 = Allthecards("The Dog", "It barks at things")
card3 = Allthecards("The Jazz", "It hears things")
card4 = Allthecards("The Candles", "It feels things")
card5 = Allthecards("The Heat", "It burns things")

cardlist = ['card1','card2','card3','card4','card5']

def getcard():
    return(random.choice(cardlist))
thecard =  getcard()

def whichcard():
    if thecard == "card1":
        return(card1.name + " "+ card1.story)
    elif thecard == "card2":
        return(card2.name + " "+ card2.story)
    elif thecard == "card3":
        return(card3.name + " "+ card3.story)
    elif thecard == "card4":
        return(card4.name + " "+ card4.story)
    elif thecard == "card5":
        return(card5.name + " "+ card5.story)
    else:
        return thecard

what = whichcard()

thebutton.bind('<Return>',thecard)
thebutton.bind('<Return>',what)
thebutton.pack()    
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve] for a better code piece.

Comment: Your second `bind` overwrites the first one.

Comment: Also, note that `bind`s above do effectively nothing. I don't think you're passing correct arguments.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time, I will look at your link and see what I can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `getcard()` method only once. That's reason you are seeing the same message everytime.

Change your `presentcard()` to the following.

```
def presentcard():
    global thecard
    thecard = getcard()
    what = whichcard()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("this is your card", what)
```

It'll give what you want.

Also, if you pass a parameter to the `def whichcard()` function like `def whichcard(thecard)`, you won't have to use `global thecard` everywhere in the program. So, the function will change to

```
def presentcard():
    thecard = getcard()
    what = whichcard(thecard)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("this is your card", what)
```

Avoid using global variables like you are using in your code. It becomes hard to reuse the functions. Just pass parameters to the functions.

Comment: Hey, thank you for solving my issue. 
I always read around guides and tutorials and they always say the same thing 'DO NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES.'  It didn't occur to me that just putting something = function anywhere made it global, although it makes sense because I'm not tying it to a specific class or anything. It didn't occur to me to tie the functions to the button function.